# How to close a path from the internal side in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to find the right way to close a path of lines drawed in a HTML5 canvas.

The lines are drawed from a particular list of points that are calculated to make the lines always of length 100 if watched from the internal side of the path.

The problem is that when I want to close the path, the last line will be oblique: so what are the calculations to be made to the first and to the last point of the list to close the path in the way I want?

JSFiddle with an example of list of points: https://jsfiddle.net/r7fndb0q/

```js
function draw() {
  const lines = [
    [
      [20, 20],
      [120, 20]
    ],
    [
      [120, 20],
      [220, 20]
    ],
    [
      [225, 15],
      [225, 125]
    ],
    [
      [230, 130],
      [120, 130]
    ]
  ]
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

    for (let i in lines) {
      context.beginPath()
      context.moveTo(lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1])
      context.lineTo(lines[i][1][0], lines[i][1][1])
      context.strokeStyle = "black"
      context.lineWidth = 10
      context.stroke()
    }

    // This is the line between last and first point with no calculations on them
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(120, 130)  // what calculations to be made?
    context.lineTo(20, 20)  // what calculations to be made?
    context.strokeStyle = "black"
    context.lineWidth = 10
    context.stroke()
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Actual result:
[image]

Expected result (the last line has been drawn by hand):
[image]

Comment: Simply remove the last block of code...